# I can't build the quasar by the tslint issue of electron-main.dev.js/electron-main.js. I did never edit these standard two files after project setup

Tags: typescript, eslint, quasar-framework, quasar

I did run **yarn quasar build**. but it was failed as the tslint issue of electron-main.dev.js and electron-main.js.  I did never edit the two files after project setup.

[image]

How can I fix these issues?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, I think that this will work for everyone : https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/8422